# Append(Map) keys from json array to another son array

Tags: python, json, jq, transpose

I have 2 `json` files:

**file1.json**

```
[
 {
  "name":"value",
  "description":"value"
 },
 {
  "name":"value1",
  "description":"value1"
 }
]
```

**file2.json**

```
[
 {
  "url":"value"   
 },
 {
  "url":"value1"
 }
]
```

**Expected result:**

```
[
 {
  "name":"value",
  "description":"value"
  "url":"value"

 },
 {
  "name":"value1",
  "description":"value1",
  "url":"value1"
 }
]
```

I tried with `jq` :

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1 file2
```

I tried with python but I am not familiar and it din't work.Thanks in advance.

Comment: for your consideration, alternatively the same JSON merge could be achieved using a _walk-path_  unix utility _jtc_: **`<file1.json jtc -w[:] -mi file2.json -i[:]`** - will deliver you the same result. Or, if you like to apply changes right into the source file (let it be `file1.json`): **`jtc -w[:] -mi file2.json -i[:] -f file1.json`**. If you like I can elaborate on the usage in a separate answer. (I'm a developer of the tool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json
li=[]
with open('file1.json') as f:
    li1 = json.load(f)
with open('file2.json') as f:
    li2 = json.load(f)
for a in zip(li1,li2):  # where l1 is first list, l2 is second list
    dict={}
    dict.update(a[0])
    dict.update(a[1])
    li.append(dict)

print(li)
# [{'name': 'value', 'description': 'value', 'url': 'value'}, {'name': 'value1', 'description': 'value1', 'url': 'value1'}]
```

**OR**

```
from collections import ChainMap
import json
with open('file1.json') as f:
    li1 = json.load(f)
with open('file2.json') as f:
    li2 = json.load(f)
li=[dict(ChainMap(*a)) for a in zip(li1,li2)]
print(li)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

With jq, thanks to `transpose`, it's a one-liner:

```
    jq -s 'transpose | map(add)' file1.json file2.json
```

```
[
  {
    "name": "value",
    "description": "value",
    "url": "value"
  },
  {
    "name": "value1",
    "description": "value1",
    "url": "value1"
  }
]
```